# row labels are missing on new page RDLC reports

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdlc, ssrs-tablix, rdl

I have RDLC report on which I have multiple rows for every employee, I hides employee names after 1st row, right!
Now I have a issue when same employee's rows goes to next page it shows widowed records (without employee name). 
To hide employee name on next rows I am using this code:

> =IIF(Fields!Name.Value <> Previous(Fields!Name.Value), Fields!Name.Value, nothing)

I also tried adding new group, and got rank from stored procedure, but nothing helps.
Is there any way to get that if the row is 1st row of page?
Or any other way to achieve the same?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally I Resolved this issue by 1st adding group on top level with this formula

`=CEILING(RowNumber(Nothing)/50)`

and in the text box this group returns me row number according to each page, So,I updated my formula for text box to:

`=IIF(Fields!Name.Value <> Previous(Fields!Name.Value) OR RowNumber("PageRowGroup")=1, Fields!Name.Value, nothing)`